# ReferenceError: file is not defined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const FirebaseService = require("../service/firebase.service");
FirebaseService.uploadFileToFirebaseStore( file , fileName );

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination:function(req, file ,cb){
     cb(null, './uploads' );
 },
  
 filename: function(req, file ,cb){
     cb(null, new Date().getTime() + path.extname(file.originalname));
 }

});

const fileFilter = (req, file ,cb) => {
   if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ||file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
     cb(null,true);
   }else{
       cb(new Error('Unsupported file'), false);
   }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize:1024*1024*10
    },
    fileFilter:fileFilter`enter code here`
});

module.exports= {
    upload:upload
}
```

This is the node js code. I write this code to upload my image to firebase. But I can't understand how to solve this problem.

---------------------------------Error -------------------------------------
FirebaseService.uploadFileToFirebaseStore( file , fileName );
^
ReferenceError: file is not defined

app.js

```
// import Koa from "koa";
const Koa = require("koa");
require("./dal");
const cors = require("@koa/cors");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const user = require("./routes/user.route");

const app = new Koa();

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cors());

app.use(user.routes()).use(user.allowedMethods());

app.use((ctx) => {
  ctx.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
  ctx.body = "Route Not Found !!!";
  ctx.status = 404;
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Application is running on port 3000");
});
```

index.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});


client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(-1);
  }
  console.log("Sucessfully connected to MongoDB");
});

module.exports = client;
```

user.dao.js

```
const users = require("./index").db("Hello").collection("hello");
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
    const insertUser = async ({ firstName, lastName, username, password }) => {
  const user = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    username,
    password,
  };
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  // now we set user password to hashed password
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  const result = await users.insertOne(user);
  return result;
};

const login = async ({ username, password }) => {
  const user = await users.findOne({ username: username });
  if (user) {
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (validPassword) {
      console.log("Valid password");
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid Password");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("User does not exist");
  }
};
const getAllUsers = () => {
  const result = users.find();
  return result.toArray();
};

const getUser = async (id) => {
  const result = await users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) });
  return result;
};

const updateUser = async (id, { firstName, lastName }) => {
  const updateDetails = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
  };
  const result = await users.replaceOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, updateDetails);
  return result;
};

const deleteUser = (id) => {
  const result = users.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) });
  return result;
};
module.exports = { insertUser, getAllUsers, getUser, updateUser, deleteUser };
```

user.api.js

```
const {
  insertUser,
  getAllUsers,
  getUser,
  updateUser,
  deleteUser,
} = require("../dal/user.dao");

const insertUserApi = async ({ firstName, lastName }) => {
  const user = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
  };
  return await insertUser(user);
};

const getAllUsersApi = () => {
  return getAllUsers();
};

const getUserApi = (id) => {
  return getUser(id);
};

const updateUserApi = (id, { firstName, lastName }) => {
  const updateDetails = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
  };
  return updateUser(id, updateDetails);
};

const deleteUserApi = (id) => {
  return deleteUser(id);
};
module.exports = {
  insertUserApi,
  getAllUsersApi,
  getUserApi,
  updateUserApi,
  deleteUserApi,
};
```

user.routes.js

```
const Router = require("@koa/router");
const {
  insertUserApi,
  getAllUsersApi,
  getUserApi,
  updateUserApi,
  deleteUserApi,
} = require("../api/user.api");

const router = new Router({
  prefix: "/api/user",
});

router.post("/add", async (ctx) => {
  let user = ctx.request.body;
  user = await insertUserApi(user);
  ctx.response.status = 200;
  ctx.body = user;
});

router.get("/getUsers", async (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = await getAllUsersApi();
});

router.get("/getUser/:id", async (ctx) => {
  let userId = ctx.params.id;
  ctx.body = await getUserApi(userId);
});

router.put("/update/:id", async (ctx) => {
  let userId = ctx.params.id;
  let user = ctx.request.body;
  user = await updateUserApi(userId, user);
  ctx.body = user;
});

router.delete("/delete/:id", async (ctx) => {
  let userId = ctx.params.id;
  ctx.body = await deleteUserApi(userId);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling this part of the code:

```
FirebaseService.uploadFileToFirebaseStore( file , fileName );
```

Before `file` and `filename` are defined.

Comment: how to defined it